# Internet Explorer - Flexbox Image Ratio

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

The following fiddle shows image ratio correctly in Chrome / Firefox.

However in Internet Explorer the images (which should be square) retain their original height in the flexbox layout when being resized to fit their container.

http://jsfiddle.net/minlare/knyagjk5/

```
<section>
<article>
    <div class="details">
        <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/rb8Y38eilRM/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="face"/>
        <h4>Name</h4>
        <div class="description">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a ultrices lectus. Curabitur molestie volutpat mattis.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
<article>
    <div class="details">
        <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/rb8Y38eilRM/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="face"/>
        <h4>Name</h4>
        <div class="description">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a ultrices lectus. Curabitur molestie volutpat mattis. Fusce fermentum auctor mauris, auctor lacinia mauris ornare faucibus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
</section>

section{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
article{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -moz-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;

    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    -ms-flex-align: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    -moz-align-items: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;

    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.details{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;

    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #666;
}
.image{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
h4{
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.description{
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -moz-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

How can this be prevented / fixed?

Comment: I think this is a known bug in IE11 (your code works fine in IE10). Perhaps a js solution is needed?

Comment: @gaynorvader Thanks, didn't even consider older version of IE would work. I have used a js solution as you suggested. Answer if you want and I will accept.

Comment: Nah, leave it open in case someone has a fix, if you like you might be able to force IE10 mode using a meta tag. It's not so much a fix as a workaround. `<meta http-equiv=“X-UA-Compatible” content=“IE=10”>`

Answer (score 20):

The reason for this is a [known documented bug](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#5-column-flex-items-dont-always-preserve-intrinsic-aspect-ratios)  where IE10 and IE11 didn't *always preserve intrinsic ratios*. And the reason it works in IE10 as per @gaynorvader's comment is that the default value for 'flex' in IE10 was `0 0 auto` rather that the final spec's `0 1 auto`. Which means that in IE10, your image is seen as `flex-grow: 0` as further explained at [flexbug 6](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#6-the-default-flex-value-has-changed)

The fix here is to set your image as `flex: none;` as per: http://jsfiddle.net/hexalys/knyagjk5/12/, or add an additional container around it. But I'd advise on not making images flex items at all if you don't really need to. In this case, your `article` container is already a flex-item so I don't think you need to make another nested flex item out of the `.details` class . That seems unnecessary.

Comment: What could be done if your markup was article > link > image div / content div / footer div. For the footer to be at the bottom on each article, the link container would also need flexbox applied with the content having a flex of 1. This particular structure won't work on IE at all as the image is just rendered full height.

Answer (score 13):

Add one bit of CSS:

```
img {
  min-height: 1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/3Lb5f8pe/

Honestly, I wish I knew why this works. In light of [hexalys' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33181355/901048), I suppose this forces IE to recalculate the height/width ratios. (In any event, I applied this to my own code just now where the affected element is a label instead of an image; it worked there, too.)